# Using VS Code with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I much prefer the client side developer experience in VS code. It's more responsive, supports more syntax variants and is generally a better tool. Right now, I right click my JS folder and click "Open with Visual Studio Code" to get the experience I'm looking for, but adding new files in VS code doesn't update the .csproj for my web app. Is there a way or an extension to achieve synergy between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code is still file editor and not IDE, meaning you are still working with folder structure and not with projects even when using language extensions for c++/c#/f#/you name it.

There are language specific extensions like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucasazzola.vscode-csproj) but nothing generic